# Does NonlinearStateSpaceModel work with symbolic constants?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, control-systems

I'm trying to put a nonlinear system of two 2nd order ODEs given by:

```
eqs = 
{2 (k1 + k2) q1[t] - 2 k2 q2[t] + 2 c1 Derivative[1][q1][t] + 
   2 c2 (Derivative[1][q1][t] - Derivative[1][q2][t]) + 
   l1 (g m2 Sin[q1[t]] + g m3 Sin[q1[t]] + 
      l2 m3 Sin[q1[t] - q2[t]] Derivative[1][q2][t]^2 + 
      l1 (m2 + m3) (q1^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
      l2 m3 Cos[q1[t] - q2[t]] (q2^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]) == 
  l1 f[t] Sin[q1[t] - q2[t]], 
 2 k2 q2[t] + 2 c2 (-Derivative[1][q1][t] + Derivative[1][q2][t]) + 
   l2 m3 (g Sin[q2[t]] - 
      l1 Sin[q1[t] - q2[t]] Derivative[1][q1][t]^2 + 
      l1 Cos[q1[t] - q2[t]] (q1^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
      l2 (q2^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]) == 2 k2 q1[t]}
```

Into a nonlinear state space formulation, which I know can be done without linearization of 2nd order terms since

```
Solve[eqs, {q1''[t], q2''[t]}]
```

returns how to isolate these double slashed variables. However, when I try to

```
sys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[
  eqs, {q1[t], q2[t], q1'[t], q2'[t]}, {}, {q1[t], q2[t], q1'[t], 
   q2'[t]}, t]
```

to obtain $\mathbf{\dot{x}} = f(\mathbf{x})$ (that is, to make it a 4-row system of 1st order ODEs), it won't express it in terms of undefined $m_{i},l_{i},k_{i},c_{i},g$. If I end up defining these as numerical values, I can get the desired column vector ((4,1) matrix) even if the $f(t)$ in the first equation remains an undefined function of t.

I can't see why couldn't Mathematica handle the symbolic constants, since I suppose it would do almost the same algebraic manipulations.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be two issues.

First, you need to specify $f[t]$ as an input.

Second, terms such as the ones below are not same.

```
SameQ[(q1^′′)[t], Derivative[2][q1][t]]
```

> False

After those two fixes, you get an answer.

```
eqs = {2 (k1 + k2) q1[t] - 2 k2 q2[t] + 2 c1 Derivative[1][q1][t] + 
2 c2 (Derivative[1][q1][t] - Derivative[1][q2][t]) + 
l1 (g m2 Sin[q1[t]] + g m3 Sin[q1[t]] + 
   l2 m3 Sin[q1[t] - q2[t]] Derivative[1][q2][t]^2 + 
   l1 (m2 + m3) Derivative[2][q1][t] + 
   l2 m3 Cos[q1[t] - q2[t]] Derivative[2][q2][t]) == 
l1 f[t] Sin[q1[t] - q2[t]], 
2 k2 q2[t] + 2 c2 (-Derivative[1][q1][t] + Derivative[1][q2][t]) + 
l2 m3 (g Sin[q2[t]] - 
   l1 Sin[q1[t] - q2[t]] Derivative[1][q1][t]^2 + 
   l1 Cos[q1[t] - q2[t]] Derivative[2][q1][t] + 
   l2 Derivative[2][q2][t]) == 2 k2 q1[t]}


NonlinearStateSpaceModel[%, {q1[t], q2[t], q1'[t], q2'[t]}, {f[t]}, {q1[t], q2[t], q1'[t], q2'[t]}, t]
```

> [image]

Comment: Tyvm! I ended up doing linear eigenvalue analysis of the system lol, but I guess the same problem would arrive while doing StateSpaceModel as well, which I'll be using in a short while

Comment: Should take only a couple of seconds :) Just delete 'Nonlinear' in `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` or wrap the result above in `StateSpaceModel`.